# Zooming and Panning UILoader Image in Flash CS5

Tags: flash, ios, flash-cs5

I have an app in Flash CS5 that I am creating for iOS.  I am loading an external image to a frame with the UILoader.  I would like to be albe to use the two finger zoom and single finger up/down/left/right movements on the image I loaded with the UILoader.  How do I do this?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read about [flash.events.TransformGestureEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TransformGestureEvent.html)

Lee Brimelow posted a video tutorial a while back on The Flash Blog - "gotoAndLearn()" that you should find helpful:

[Multi Touch Gesture Applications - Learn how to use the new gesture support in Flash Player 10.1 and Adobe AIR 2.0](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=119)